# How to change the size of the dots on sns.scatterplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I would like to plot a graph with a larger size on my dots,
I have tried with `sizes=100` but it didn't work,

here's the code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[1, 3, 'weekday'], [2, 2.5, 'weekday'],[3, 2.7, 'weekend'], [4, 2.8, 'weekend'], [5, 3, 'weekday'], [6, 3.1, 'weekday'], [7, 3, 'weekday'], [8, 3.1, 'weekday'], [9, 3.1, 'weekday'], [10, 3.1, 'weekend']])

# Creating a data frame with the raw data
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['day', 'miles_walked', 'day_category'])

ax = sns.scatterplot(x='day', y='miles_walked', data=dataset, hue='day_category',sizes=100)
# Customize the axes and title
ax.set_title("Miles walked")
ax.set_xlabel("day")
ax.set_ylabel("total miles")
# Remove top and right borders
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

could somebody help please?
thank you very much,

Comment: `sizes=` is used together with `size=` to let a column of the dataframe decide over the size of individual dots. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `s` parameter of the `sns.scatterplot` function as follow:

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='day', y='miles_walked', s=100, data=dataset, hue='day_category')
```

Answer (score 3):

Is not `sizes` but `s`.

Replace

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='day', y='miles_walked', data=dataset, hue='day_category',sizes=100)
```

by

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='day', y='miles_walked', data=dataset, hue='day_category',s=100)
```